# Kill Thread and childs without crash after kill

Tags: c, multithreading, crash, pthreads

how can i to kill thread and child's ?

```
i killing the parent thread but children threads are not killed.
```

i create thread by this code :

```
pthread_attr_t  attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
pthread_create(&posixThreadID, &attr, &threadFunc, "void");
```

for kill :

```
pthread_cancel(posixThreadID);
```

Comment: yes. i think the main thread like main task. when kill main task all children tasks killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pthread_kill` to kill a specific thread. you can send `kill -9 ppid` to the parent process and it will kill all the threads in the threadgroup, if your intention is to kill all the threads in the group.